# how to optimize a problem with many constraints

Tags: java, solver, nonlinear-optimization

I want to minimize the cost of a ration of sheep where the sheep has needs like (PDI , Cabs, Pabs , UFL , UEM ...) and a have the foods who they have this needs. like in this picture:

[image]

and every food has a price where the price is the sum of the price of every food * quantity in the ration
but there is many constraints to achieve that and one of theme is the equation where the variables is the sum of percentage of the food in the ration * the value of UEM for example
i will put the equation who depends of many variable:

[image]

and the contraints are like this:

```
Apport PDIEration >= PDI

Rmic >= Rmic de l’animal

cost = ([∑(Pi *Prix Ci)]*Qc + [∑(Pi *Prix fi)]*Qf)
```

I want to do it in Java.

Comment: This is very difficult to read. You may want to reformat and clean up things a bit.

Comment: im new here , its my first post here so can u help me please ?? waht do yo mean by clean up things a bit coz i want to explain everything to help me. ok if someone want any explanation about it im here

Comment: Well, don't format your text as code like it was. If you add pictures, make sure they actually work. Things like that...

Comment: Thank you very much @JamesZ for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use an optimization library such as Apache Commons Math (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/optimization.html) or Google OR-tools (https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/java)

Comment: Thank you for the answer  i will try the second one Google OR-tools and i will see.

Comment: To be honest i don't know how how to do it , if someone has an idea how to implement apache commons math please to help because im right now in a complicate situation please